# Two IPs for a machine?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, internet, ethernet

I have a robot onboard computer (called 'C') connected wirelessly to a router, and a Ubuntu machine (called 'U') connected by wire to the same router.

'U' has IP 192.168.1.95 and can access internet, while 'C' can not access internet.

The following is what I get from`ifconfig` :

> br0:
>       Link uncap:Ethernet
>       HWaddr 00:0b:ab:ad:60:8e
>       init addr: 192.168.1.11
>       Bcast: 192.168.1.255
>       Mask: 255.255.255.0
>       .......
>
> lo:
>      Link encap: Local network
>      Intet addr:127.0.0.1
>      Mask 255.0.0.0
>      .....
>
> wlan0:
>         Link encap: Ethernet
>         HWaddr: 7c:5c:f8:25:bf:5c
>         intet addres: 192.168.0.107
>         Bcast:192.168.0.255
>         Mask: 255.255.255.0
>         ......

I can **not** ping either `192.168.1.11` or `192.168.0.107`from 'U', **neither** from 'C' to 'U'.

Have searched around about Bridge in networking, still not solved. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the `ifconfig` output from the 'C' ? why does it have a bridge?

Comment: That's also what I don't understand. Yea, it is the output of `ifconfig`. It is a onboard computer of a ground robotic vehicle.

Comment: Your configs are messed up. If your 'C' box only uses one interface wifi there's no need for a bridge. @st01k got the other problem even though you claim both boxes connect to one router for some reason they're on different subnets. post your `/etc/network/interfaces` from both boxes

Comment: The `/etc/network/interfaces` at 'U' gives `# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and if down(8) \n auto lo \n face lo inet loopback`; at 'C' it gives `auto lo br0 br0:0 \n face lo inet loopback \n bridge_ports regex etc.* \n address 192.168.1.1 \n net mask 255.255.255.0 \n face br0:0 inet dhcp`

Comment: If you only use one interface on each box take out all that bridge stuff from the /etc/network/interfaces

Answer (score 0):

The wifi adapter on C (wlan0 @ 192.168.0.107) is on a different subnet than U (192.168.1.95).  The third octet in the IP designates what subnet the IP is on because of your mask (255.255.255.0).

The bridge adapter (br0 @ 192.168.1.11) on C is on the same subnet as U, but because it can't see the wifi adapter, it won't be able to talk to the network.

If you put the C's wlan0 on the 192.168.1.0 network instead of on the 192.168.0.0 network (where it is), it should be able to communicate.  You would just need to edit the network configuration for the wlan0 adapter on C.

Comment: Where or how should I change C's wlan0?

Comment: I solved this issue by doing two things:  1. I reset the `/etc/network/interfaces` of 'C' to default: `auto lo \n face lo inet loopback`; 2. allow DHCP at 'C' when connected the Wifi.